# How can I update all UIDs of a DICOM study while maintaining its structure?

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I have a DICOM study with 3 series and want to refresh its UIDs (StudyInstanceUID, SeriesInstanceUID, SOPInstanceUID) to do some tests. All the data is in a single directory so it's not possible to tell which DICOM belongs to which series.

What I have tried is using dcmodify (dcmtk) with some generate options :

```sh
dcmodify mydirectory/*.dcm -gst -gse -gin
```

but it makes all single files different studies, the structure was broken.

Is there a way to do this or do I have to use other dcmtk tools to identify series UIDs that every single file has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-gst -gse and -gin
```

Create a new Study-, Series and SOP Instance UID for each individual image matching mydirectory/*.dcm, hence destroying the study/series structure as you already observed.

The answer is two-fold:
To assign the same UID to all images, you rather use

```
-m (0020,000D)=...
```

(this example for the Study Instance UID)

But there is no command line tool in DCMTK that I am aware of which would completely solve your problem. The storescp has an option to create subdirectories for each study (e.g. `--sort-on-study-uid`) but that does not solve the series-level problem.

With the means of DCMTK, I think you need to do some scripting work around it using `dcmdump` to dump the files to text, extracting Study- and Series Instance UID from it and then moving the file to an appropriate Study+Series folder.